# androidx.camera.view.PreviewView Causes java.lang.NullPointerException in Xamarin.Android Designer

Tags: xamarin.android, android-camera2, android-camerax

I am working on adding an `androidx.camera.view.PreviewView` to my Xamarin.Android app, but it displays a `java.lang.NullPointerException` in the Xamarin.Android Designer in Visual Studio 2022. The Details: displayed in the Designer are as follows:

```
    android.hardware.display.DisplayManager.registerDisplayListener(DisplayManager.java:414)
    androidx.camera.view.PreviewView.startListeningToDisplayChange(PreviewView.java:970)
    androidx.camera.view.PreviewView.onAttachedToWindow(PreviewView.java:299)
    android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:18347)
    android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3397)
    android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
    com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:330)
    com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:394)
    com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:271)
    mono.android.DesignerSession.loadInternal(DesignerSession.java:273)
    mono.android.DesignerSession.lambda$load$0(DesignerSession.java:223)
    mono.android.MonoDroidBroker.executeInMonoDroidContext(MonoDroidBroker.java:76)
    mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:223)
    mono.android.DesignerSession.processMessage(DesignerSession.java:676)
    mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
    mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The exact xml of the PreviewView is as follows:

```
<androidx.camera.view.PreviewView android:id="@+id/pvCurrent" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_column="0" android:layout_row="0" tools:layout_width="match_parent" tools:layout_height="150dp" tools:background="@color/Three"/>
```

I am not sure what to do, since this is my first time with PreviewView & it is a design time exception. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Probably just a limitation of the Android Designer in Visual Studio. Just like it can't handle a navigationgraph.xml without raising an exception. The android designer hasn't had any work done on it since about 2019 and totally sucks.

Use Android Studio's designer and when you get your design right, copy/paste the XML into an empty file you create with VS's android designer.

If that doesn't work then you have some other problem.